# how to update the progress to UI using Events and Delegates

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I have a button in a winform and on clicking which there will be some processing for say 5s.

during this process, I want to update the progress(ProgressBar) to UI with the % of work completed.

How to do this using Events & Delegates?

Other approaches(other than Events & Delegates) are also welcomed..

Comment: What research have you done? There's some pages on the MSDN on this topic with example code.

Comment: @ChrisF: I know how to use Events and delegates theoretically.. But in this scenario I don't know how to implement it..and also I don't even know how to do any research for this particular scenario..

Comment: That's fine, but unless you state what you've tried what's provided as an answer might be worse than no answer at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo code below. I don't have the compiler at hand so the actual ProgressBar interface could differ slightly from what I remember.

```
// service

delegate void ProgressDelegate( int CurrentValue, int MaxValue );

void BusinessProcess( ProgressDelegate progress )
{
   // do something
   progress( 20, 100 );

   // do other things
   progress( 50, 100 );

   // do yet another thing
   progress( 100, 100 );
}

// client

void Button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
   BusinessProcess(
      (current, max ) => 
      {
         this.ProgressBar1.Maximum = max;
         this.ProgressBar1.Value = current;
         this.ProgressBar1.Refresh();
      }
      );
}
```

Comment: This solves the direct question about the Progressbar but it does not address _how_ to do 5 secs of processing on a ButtonClick. This program will 'hang'.

Comment: It won't if you add `Application.DoEvents()` or anything to force pendning messages to be processed. That's why I indicated that it is a partial solution.

Comment: DoEvents() introduces a bucket of (potential) other problems. It needs a Thread.

Comment: That's a topic for separate discussion, far beyond the asker's request.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep your application responsive during the process, then use a BackgroundWorker. See MSDN Article [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). It has a c# example which shows how to report a progress.